# quickbooks SalesOrderAddRq adding issue

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbxml

Hello I am facing issue when adding SalesOrderAddRq in Quickbooks using https://packagist.org/packages/consolibyte/quickbooks

following is my XML for adding salesorder in Quickbooks and also here is tag `<ListID >` what will be the value of this is field!

further more i am getting this error when adding

Version:
PHP QuickBooks SOAP Server v3.0 at /quickbooks/qbwc

Message:

> 3140: There is an invalid reference to QuickBooks Customer
>   "john Doe" in the SalesOrder.  QuickBooks error message: Invalid
>   argument.  The specified record does not exist in the list.

Description:

> Error message received from application via getLastError(): 3140:
>   There is an invalid reference to QuickBooks Customer "john Doe" in the
>   SalesOrder.  QuickBooks error message: Invalid argument.  The
>   specified record does not exist in the list.

```
 public function _addSaleorderRequest($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
 {

    // Do something here to load data using your model
    //$data = $this->yourmodel->getCustomerData($ID);
    // Build the qbXML request from $data
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <?qbxml version="4.0"?>
 <QBXML>
      <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <SalesOrderAddRq  requestID="' . $requestID . '">
          <SalesOrderAdd>
              <CustomerRef> <!-- required -->
                <ListID >' . $requestID . '</ListID> <!-- optional -->
                <FullName >john Doe</FullName> <!-- optional -->
            </CustomerRef>
            <TxnDate>2013-05-23</TxnDate>
            <RefNumber>$requestID</RefNumber>
            <BillAddress>
                <Addr1>China Town One</Addr1>
                <Addr2>China Town Two</Addr2>
                <City>Pta Nai</City>
                <State>Dont Know</State>
                <PostalCode>420420</PostalCode>
                <Country>PK</Country>
            </BillAddress>
            <ShipAddress>
                <Addr1>China Town One</Addr1>
                <Addr2>China Town Two</Addr2>
                <City>Houston</City>
                <State>TX</State>
                <PostalCode>77074</PostalCode>
                <Country>US</Country>
            </ShipAddress>
            <SalesOrderLineAdd>
                <ItemRef>
                    <FullName>Booklets:CB1-101</FullName>
                </ItemRef>
                <Desc>CHF</Desc>
                <Quantity>15</Quantity>
                <Amount>59.25</Amount>
            </SalesOrderLineAdd>
            <SalesOrderLineAdd>
                <ItemRef>
                    <FullName>Booklets:CB3-101</FullName>
                </ItemRef>
                <Desc>High Blood Pressure</Desc>
                <Quantity>15</Quantity>
                <Amount>59.25</Amount>
            </SalesOrderLineAdd>
            <SalesOrderLineAdd>
                <ItemRef>
                    <FullName>Booklets:DB1-101</FullName>
                </ItemRef>
                <Desc>Diabetes Type 1 or 2 with Insulin</Desc>
                <Quantity>15</Quantity>
                <Amount>59.25</Amount>
            </SalesOrderLineAdd>
            <SalesOrderLineAdd>
                <ItemRef>
                    <FullName>Booklets:DB2-101</FullName>
                </ItemRef>
                <Desc>Diabetes Type 1 or 2 w/o Insulin</Desc>
                <Quantity>15</Quantity>
                <Amount>59.25</Amount>
            </SalesOrderLineAdd>
        </SalesOrderAdd>
    </SalesOrderAddRq>
</QBXMLMsgsRq>
 </QBXML>';

    return $xml;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message:

> 3140: There is an invalid reference to QuickBooks Customer "john Doe"
>   in the SalesOrder. QuickBooks error message: Invalid argument. The
>   specified record does not exist in the list.

Means that you're telling QuickBooks to add a Sales Order for customer `John Doe`, but that customer *does not exist* in QuickBooks.

You can't add a Sales Order to a customer that does not exist.

This is akin to how every single relational database system works -- you have foreign keys/dependencies between records that you need to satisfy.

This:

```
<ListID >' . $requestID . '</ListID>
```

Is not a a valid `ListID` value. You need to pass in a valid `ListID` value.

You're passing in the `$requestID` value for the specific qbXML request, which is completely unrelated in every way to a `ListID` for a customer.

Please pass a valid Customer `ListID` value (or alternatively, pass in a valid Customer `Name` value and don't pass the `ListID` tag at all).

Comment: Thanks for your answering

Comment: Means that you're telling QuickBooks to add a Sales Order for customer John Doe, but that customer does not exist in QuickBooks.

You can't add a Sales Order to a customer that does not exist.                                     
@keith I have added this customer John Doe using qbXML with CustomerAddRq and customer successfully has been added and showing in QB as well. but when i am trying to add salesorder against this customer then getting this error secondly is this ListID required ? if yes then from where to get this valid ListID

Comment: You can use the ListID *or* a FullName to refer to the customer. Don't use both. Use one or the other. The customer's ListID is returned to you in the response from your CustomerAdd request.